# Is there a way to add an Paypal Icon in Squarespace's billing section of the checkout page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, squarespace

So I have a client who wants to add the Paypal icon under the billing section of the checkout page of her Squarespace account, because she has Paypal buttons for the service she provides. I was wondering if there was a way, either through a code or css to get that icon in there?

Comment: Before you add the icon , make sure you ask for permission from the author ( paypal in this case ). Without their consent, you or your company might end up in a legal lawsuit.

Comment: Also, look at the paypal api. This might provide what you are looking for : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/